# Controlling the number of instances of an application running through a Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have a windows service which watches a folder for new file(s) being created. Once a file is dropped in, the service will launch another app sending this file path as an argument.

I am looking for a way to control the number of instances of the second app the windows service can spawn, for instance if there is a way to set only 5 instances of the second app should be spawned.

I have tried using a Semaphore with a value of 1 in the second app, but this makes the second app execute one file at a time when more than one file is dropped, but the Windows Service launches the number of instances as the number of files in the hot folder. I don't want to disturb the second app and want to remove the Semaphore out of it.

Both the Windows service and the Second App are .NET applications.

Comment: Global semaphore should help you, but I havn't understand. It's Windows Services launches 2nd app multiple times then or Windows Service is launched multiple times?

Comment: Since your code (the service) is creating the new processes (and since it is easy to check whether processes you have launched are still running) it should be trivial to keep track of how many processes are active.

Comment: Hello everyone, Regfor it's the service which launches the second app. For now going with the solution suggested by Harry and Jaster till I get a way to do this with WCF via IPC suggested by Jaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick & Dirty: Use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class and monitor the amount of processes with a specific name. You can subscribe to the Process.Exited event or just poll in a loop.

Proper Solution: Use a [WCF](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks) based IPC and create a handshake between service & clients

Comment: Hi Jaster, thanks for your suggestion, will go with the Quick & Dirty. Any suggestions or links that can  guide on the Proper Solution using WCF based IPC?

Comment: check my WCF link within the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a semaphore, did you try setting it's initial value to 5?  This would allow 5 concurrent accesses to the semaphore before it blocks.

Comment: Hi Spence, the second app which is launched by the service implements a Semaphore with a value of 1. Due to a bug in the design of the second app, it hangs some time and the only way to end it is through Task Manager. The other instances are waiting forever as the initial Semaphore is never released.